# Склеить строки используя файл конфигураций

Tags: delphi

Есть текстовый файл **(База.txt)** в котором подана вот такая информация:

Вот тут изменились условия то есть поиск конфигурации между знаками **№ и :**

```
Doc12№ver.01:От 01.01.2020
Doc24№ver.02:От 02.01.2020
Doc15№ver.03:От 03.01.2020
Doc18№ver.04:От 04.01.2020
Doc22№ver.05:От 05.01.2020
```

А файл **(Конфигурация.txt)**, в котором указаны конфигурации - выглядит вот так:

```
№ver.01=\0021
№ver.02=\0034
№ver.03=\0070
№ver.04=\0072
№ver.05=\0871
```

Программа заходит в текстовый документ **Конфигурация.txt** и смотрит что написано напротив **№ver.01, №ver.02, №ver.03, №ver.04,№ver.05**: И подставляет результаты в файл **(База.txt)** выходя из конфигурации. На выходе получается текстовый файл - **Результат.txt** в котором информация сохранена уже в таком виде:

```
Doc12№ver.01:От 01.01.2020\0021
Doc24№ver.02:От 02.01.2020\0034
Doc15№ver.03:От 03.01.2020\0070
Doc18№ver.04:От 04.01.2020\0072
Doc22№ver.05:От 05.01.2020\0871
```

**Вот код и он работает все отлично - но: Как мне сохранить в отдельный файл те строки которые не подошли под конфигурацию ?.**

Comment: Конечно можно. Или у вас вопрос в другом? Всегда ли строки идут по возрастанию номера?

Comment: @becouse, Нет. Строки идут не всегда - они могут быть не по возрастанию а даже и рандомно.

Comment: каков размер файлов то? в стринглист оба файла, если не большие, разделители указать. и циклом по базе.

Comment: @teran, Код сделал но теперь не могу сохранить остаток через else. Если не сложно посмотрите мой ответ в теме ? Где допущена ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так:
**Вот код и он работает все отлично - но: Как мне сохранить в отдельный файл те строки которые не подошли под конфигурацию ?.**

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  slver: TStringList;
  sf, df, df2: TextFile;
  s,s2: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  slver := TStringList.Create;
  slver.LoadFromFile('Конфигурация.txt');
  slver.Delimiter := '=';
  slver.DelimitedText := slver.Text;

  AssignFile(sf, 'База.txt');
  Reset(sf);
  AssignFile(df, 'Save.txt');
  Rewrite(df);
  // Вот тут нужно сохранить то чно не подошло под фильтр !!!!!
  AssignFile(df2, 'Save2.txt');
  Rewrite(df2);


  while not EOF(sf) do begin
    ReadLn(sf, s);
    i := 0;
    while i < slver.Count do begin
      if Pos(slver.Strings[i], s) > 0 then begin
        s := s + slver.Strings[i+1];
        WriteLn(df, s);
        // Тут я исключаю те строки что не подошли под фильтр
        Break;
      end;
      // Знаю что где то тут нужно прописать else и далее WriteLn(df2, s) но как ?;
      Inc(i);
      Inc(i);
    end;
  end;
  CloseFile(sf);
  CloseFile(df);
  slver.Free;
end;
```

Comment: @teran, Код сделал но теперь не могу сохранить остаток через else. Если не сложно посмотрите мой ответ в теме ? Где допущена ошибка?